# не могу решить задачу. Либо не понимаю условия , либо ошибка в коде

Tags: python

Друзья, на одном портале была размещена задача :

Возьмите данные по безработице в городе Москва: https://video.ittensive.com/python-advanced/data-9753-2019-07-25.utf.csv Сгруппируйте данные по годам, если в году меньше 6 значений, отбросьте эти годы. Постройте модель линейной регрессии по годам среднего значения отношения UnemployedDisabled к UnemployedTotal (процента людей с ограниченными возможностями) за месяц и ответьте, какое ожидается значение в 2020 году при сохранении текущей политики города Москвы?

я ее решил:

**

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    pd.options.display.max_rows = 1000
    data = pd.read_csv("https://video.ittensive.com/python-advanced/data-9753-2019-07-             25.utf.csv", delimiter = ";")
    data = data.groupby("Year").filter(lambda x : x["UnemployedTotal"].count() < 6)
    data["Year"] = data["Year"].astype("category")
    data_group = data.groupby("Year").mean()
    x = np.array(data_group.index).reshape(len(data_group.index),1)
    y=np.array(data_group["UnemployedDisabled"]/data_group["UnemployedTotal"]*100).reshape(len(data_group.index),1)
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(x, y)
    plt.scatter(x,y , color ="orange")
    x = np.append(x,[2020]).reshape(len(data_group.index)+1,1)
    plt.plot(x, model.predict(x), color = "blue", linewidth = 3)
    plt.show()

    print(model.predict(np.array(2020).reshape(1,1)))
    #print(data_group)
```

Но получил ответ 1,5 ,  который не проходит . Есть подозрение , что не понял условие, а именно что в итоге я должен получить ?

Answer (score 0):

Годы в которых меньше 6 значений нужно отбросить, а вы наоборот только их и считаете.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! :) Но разве этой строкой я не собираю новый фрейм     data["Year"] = data["Year"].astype("category") , в который не вошли отброшенные? Если ошибка , будьте любезны подсказать как правильно?